# Oracle Query optimization for this query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Please suggest how to improve below query /index for faster results.

Query

```
SELECT Tab1.pk, Tab1.c_RetryCount, Tab1.c_TimeCreated  
  FROM Table1 Tab1  
 WHERE ( ( Tab1.c_node = :1 
           OR Tab1.c_node IS NULL ) 
       AND ( ( Tab1.c_RetryCount < :2 
               AND Tab1.c_TimeUpdated < :3 ) 
            OR Tab1.c_RetryCount < :4 ) 
       AND Tab1.c_SentStatus = :5 ) 
   AND ( Tab1.c_Active = 1 ) 
   AND ( Tab1.c_DelFlag = 0 ) 
   AND ( Tab1.c_Shard = :6 )  
 ORDER BY Tab1.c_RetryCount ASC, Tab1.c_TimeCreated ASC
```

Plan hash value: 2132878353

---

```
| Id  | Operation                     | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                 |       |       |     4 (100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                |                 |    43 |  2279 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   CONCATENATION               |                 |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| Table1          |     1 |    53 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_VOY52S_H881K4 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| Table1          |    42 |  2226 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_VOY52S_H881K4 |     2 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

---

```
   3 - filter(("Tab1"."c_DelFlag"=0 AND "Tab1"."c_ACTIVE"=1))
   4 - access("Tab1"."c_Shard"=:6 AND "Tab1"."c_node" IS NULL 
              AND "Tab1"."c_SENTSTATUS"=:5)
       filter(("Tab1"."c_SENTSTATUS"=:5 AND ("Tab1"."c_RETRYCOUNT"<:4 OR 
              ("Tab1"."c_TIMEUPDATED"<:3 AND "Tab1"."c_RETRYCOUNT"<:2))))
   5 - filter(("Tab1"."c_DelFlag"=0 AND "Tab1"."c_ACTIVE"=1))
   6 - access("Tab1"."c_Shard"=:6 AND "Tab1"."c_node"=:1 AND 
              "Tab1"."c_SENTSTATUS"=:5)
       filter(("Tab1"."c_SENTSTATUS"=:5 AND ("Tab1"."c_RETRYCOUNT"<:4 OR 
              ("Tab1"."c_TIMEUPDATED"<:3 AND "Tab1"."c_RETRYCOUNT"<:2)) AND 
              LNNVL("Tab1"."c_node" IS NULL)))
```

### Table Table1 indexes:

```
  I_VOY52S_19HS9Y5 (c_SENTSTATUS, c_ACTIVE, c_DelFlag) 
  I_VOY52S_1CPSX8O (c_node) 
  I_VOY52S_H881K4 (c_Shard, c_node, c_RETRYCOUNT, c_TIMEUPDATED, c_SENTSTATUS) 
  P_VOY52S_142KZ99 (pk)
```

Comment: What is the query performance like at the moment, and what performance are you aiming for?

Comment: How many records in the table? is it partitioned by any way? does it used for mostly reads or for DML operations also? in addition can you add default value to c_node?

Answer (score 0):

Other than c_Shard, the other two single-value filters being applied to every row use c_Active, c_DelFlag. So, it is a pretty good guess that adding these to the I_VOY52S_H881K4 index will improve performance of this one query.

Or, a new index :

```
    I_VOY52S_XXXXX (c_Shard, c_Active, c_DelFlag, 
                    c_node, c_RETRYCOUNT, c_TIMEUPDATED, c_SENTSTATUS)
```

You could even throw in pk and c_timeCreated near the end to keep the query index-only.

Of course, creating a new index like that might be totally impractical when one considers other query, or data-volume; but, since you did not mention this, I'm assuming zero cost to having another index that's perfect for this one query.

So, you'd get:

```
    I_VOY52S_XXXXX (c_Shard, c_Active, c_DelFlag, 
                    c_node, c_RETRYCOUNT, c_TIMEUPDATED, c_SENTSTATUS, 
                    c_timecreated, pk)
```